# NativeScript that opens a website based on it's name?

Tags: android, mobile, webview, apk, nativescript

Is it possible to open a website (from a NativeScript App) that does not show the top part of browser like the address line and tabs and opens it in landscape?

Possible to change what page that NativeScript App is opening without recompiling? with something like APK Edit? Or maybe can a NativeScript App be aware of it's name or some else like configured metadata outside the APK during deployment or publishing?

So the idea is an APK who's only job is to open a web site, but we don't want to recompile to determine which site it opens when shared or deployed. Also, don't want it to be obvious it's opened a website.

Comment: It's possible but it's not recommended - I don't think anyone would use an app just to access a website within. In case if you are planning for iOS too, Apple will reject such apps. It will be obvious that you are embedding a remote website to any user with fair knowledge of smart phones, just by the UX. If you are still interested in proceeding, you could just use a WebView within your app and load your site.

Comment: I have a responsive web site written in Bulma.  My subdomains perform very specific functions but are separate and distinct.  I'd like to offer some of them as Mobile Apps but don't want to re-code and have to maintain two code bases.  I think it's possible with Progressive Web Apps(PWA) but was hoping do something like those services are doing that convert your web page to a APK, but dynamically somehow.   Yes WebView, but dynamically based on something in the deployment, app config or name.